# conflict with autoLayout

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode7, ios9.2

Hi guys I got situation where in if I embed NAVIGATION CONTROLLER to VIEW CONTROLLER containing table view, their is some gap gets created between NAVIGATION BAR and PROTOTYPE CELL.
Even if I drag and drop NAVIGATION CONTROLLER to canvas and delete its ROOT VIEW CONTROLLER and connect it to the VIEW CONTROLLER containing table view as ROOT VIEW CONTROLLER, then also the same situation occurs. I even try changing the height values of PROTOTYPE CELL but the same thing.
photo link https://db.tt/up0sZypj

This situation doesn't occur only when I directly uses NAVIGATION CONTROLLER with its own ROOT VIEW CONTROLLER.
photo link https://db.tt/JssxrNbe

So please help me out of this situation.
I have given photo link because I can't attach photos as I don't have 10 reputed posts, am really sorry for that.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't but the images in the question? The links may be blocked and people don't like clicking on them.

Comment: am new here so i have to post atleast 10 post... to put pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may help you.
Uncheck option for ScrollView inset for UIViewController in which your TableView resides.

[image]

Comment: Can i get your email address?

Comment: yes i did but i need your email to contact you for my queries if you are ready to help me in my situations....

Comment: Sorry, i can not make my email address public.

Comment: please visit this link to download my project and please help me to solve my problems.  please read the read me file. https://db.tt/HIsIDdRu

Comment: Sorry dear, I am poor at SQLite. Post your issues, you will definitely get solutions. Thanks

Comment: can you please have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582962/show-more-button-next-to-end-of-text-swift

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the top constraint of your tableView set to the top layout guide and have extended edges under top bars enabled.

If so you can either remove the top constraint and drag the top of your tableView to top of your superview; underneath the navigation controller. Then set the top constraint to 0 to the top of your superview.

or

You can uncheck the extended edges under top bars checkbox in the attribute inspector when the UIViewController is selected

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I tried whatever you told me. I changed the top constrain of the TableView to -63 and the TableView went beneath the navigation bar but rather than doing this I want to know why the Prototype Cells's height get increased when I embed in the NavigationController manually.

Comment: From the improper image you posted it is not that the prototype cell is getting bigger. The padding from the top comes from the view controller setting content insets of the table view, so that the table views content can show through the navigation bar when scrolling.

Comment: so please can you tell me proper steps.... am new here so i doesn't know much... please tell me step by step what to do..... thanks alot for your valuable time....

Comment: Please can you see this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632326/multiple-collectionview-in-multiple-tableview-cells