# Show more button next to end of text Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel, uitextview

I want to show more button at the end of the text or below if there isn't enough space. I don't understand how Apple developers did this?
Please answer in swift. After clicking on more button i want to show all the text. change the button to less.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add "...Read More" to the end of UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309247/add-read-more-to-the-end-of-uilabel)

Comment: @AhmadF, bro could you please take a look my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966983/how-to-set-label-height-for-auto-adjust-in-read-more-less-with-swift-3 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a great CocoaPod for the functionality you're looking for.

https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView

This will allow you to set a maximum number of lines and customise the text append to the end of the trimmed text. You can change the font and color since it is an `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wanted to do manual implementation so I was asking for some code.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale, bro could you please take a look to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966983/how-to-set-label-height-for-auto-adjust-in-read-more-less-with-swift-3 ?

Answer (score -5):

If you add more than 4-5 view controllers to a TabBar Controller, either in storyboard or programmatically(adding array of controllers to a tabar controller), it automatically show a more item as a tabar item in TabBar.

Comment: Answering the wrong question